# Complex ViewModel. View returns an empty ViewModel. [HttpPost] Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with the action that recives a complex ViewModel by POST and all of its object components are null, even though I have initialized them in Action and have returned the whole ViewModel to the View using GET method.

Let me explain the situation. I have a complex model for a View that consists of three sections: `Applicant` details, `Application` details, and a list of `Recordings`. This View is complex to (1) let me see the details of `Applicant` I am creating application for, (2) have a list of recordings I would like to choose from which then I can add to `Application`. This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel
{
    // Applicant
    public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

    // Application
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public SelectList UsageTypeSelectList { get; private set; }
    public SelectList UsageEndAppSelectList { get; private set; }

    // Recordings
    public IEnumerable<RecordingViewModelApp>
                                RecordingsViewModelApp { get; set; }

    public ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel()
        : this(new MyDBContext())
    {
    }
    public ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel(MyDBContext dbContext)
    {
            PopulateUsageTypeSelectList(dbContext);
            PupulateUsageEndAppSelectList(dbContext);
    }

    private void PopulateUsageTypeSelectList(MyDBContext dbContext,
                                int? usageTypeSelected = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<UsageType> utQuery =
                dbContext.UsageTypes.OrderBy(
                ut => ut.UsageTypeName).ToList();
        this.UsageTypeSelectList =
                new SelectList(utQuery,
                    "UsageTypeID",
                    "UsageTypeName",
                    usageTypeSelected);
    }
    private void PupulateUsageEndAppSelectList(
                                MyDBContext dbContext,
                                int? usageEndAppSelected = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<UsageEndApp> ueaQuery =
                dbContext.UsageEndApps.OrderBy(uea => uea.UsageEndAppName).ToList();
        this.UsageEndAppSelectList =
                new SelectList(ueaQuery,
                    "UsageEndAppID",
                    "UsageEndAppName",
                    usageEndAppSelected);
    }
}
```

In the controller I simply populate a list of recordings for `RecordingViewModelApp`, put details of an applicant to `Applicant` and leave the `Application` object empty to be filled in a View.

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? ApplicantID)
    {
        if (ApplicantID == null)
        {
            // Error 400. Bad Request Exception
        }
        ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel viewModel = null;
        using (MyDBContext dbContext = new MyDBContext())
        {
            Applicant applicant =
                    dbContext.Applicants.Find(ApplicantID);
            if (applicant == null)
            {
                // Error 404. Http not found
            }
            List<RecordingViewModelApp> recordings =
                    getViewModel(
                            dbContext.Recordings.ToList(),
                            dbContext);
            viewModel =
                    new ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel(dbContext);
            viewModel.Applicant = applicant;
            viewModel.RecordingsViewModelApp = recordings;
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The problem is that when I return the ViewModel (`ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel`) back to the `[HttpPost] Create()` Action, all the View Model's components are null, e.g. the list of `RecordingViewModelApp` is null. What Am I missing? I would need to understand what's going on behind the scene and why default model binding doesn't work.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create_post(
                    ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel viewModelToValidate)
{
    // Validation against Application only and TryToUpdate() etc.
}
```

CHeers!

---

EDIT:

The View

```
@model Project.ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel

@{
    string applicantDetails = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
            Model.Applicant.title, Model.Applicant.firstName, Model.Applicant.lastName);
    ViewBag.Title = "Create a new application for " + applicantDetails;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h3>Details of the applicant</h3>
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.Applicant.ApplicantID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.Application.ApplicationID)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.firstName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.lastName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.telephone)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.mobile)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Applicant.email)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.title)</td>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.firstName)</td>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.lastName)</td>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.telephone)</td>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.mobile)</td>
            <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Applicant.email)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr /> // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <h3>Details of the application</h3>
    <table id="main">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.ApplicationNo)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Application.ApplicationNo) 
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.ApplicationNo)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.StartDate)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Application.StartDate) 
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.StartDate)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.EndDate)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Application.EndDate) 
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.EndDate)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.UsageTypeID)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.Application.UsageTypeID, Model.UsageTypeSelectList, "-- Select Usage --")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.UsageTypeID)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.UsageEndAppID)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(item => Model.Application.UsageEndAppID, Model.UsageEndAppSelectList, "-- Select Type --")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.UsageEndAppID)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label first-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.linkToPaperVer)</td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Application.linkToPaperVer) 
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.linkToPaperVer)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td  class="editor-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(item => Model.Application.Info)
            </td>
            <td class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Application.Info) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => Model.Application.Info)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr /> // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <h3>List of recordings</h3>
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Recordings/_List_App.cshtml", Model.RecordingsViewModelApp);
    <hr /> // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Applicants")
</div>
```

---

EDIT 2

PartialView:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.RecordingViewModelApp>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        <table class="data-in-table">
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSelected)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileLocation)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnteredDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="display-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => item.IsSelected)</td>
                    <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FileLocation)</td>
                    <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EnteredDate)</td>
                    <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Duration)</td>
                    <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3>No recordings attached to this Patient</h3>
}
```

---

EDIT 3

The `RecordingViewModelApp`:

```
public class RecordingViewModel
{
    public int RecordingID { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnteredDate { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class RecordingViewModelApp : RecordingViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: Have you tried not calling the `Model` in your view but using the `item` @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Application.ApplicationNo). If it doesn't help, please add the rendered HTML code of the view

Comment: I cannot do it now. VS2010 is installed in different machine so I have to wait until tomorrow. I can only say that View is rendered correctly when the model is returns from GET action. When it returns back to POST, components are null. The Rendered `PartialView` is referring to `RecodingViewModel` via all helpers like `DisplayFor` and `DisplayNameFor`. I don't how this would affect the model itself!

Comment: You will need to post the names of the inputs from the rendered HTML, then it will be clear why you have nulls in your action  :)

Comment: But not only `RecodingViewModel`component is null, `Applicant` component is null either! EDIT. I don't use hardcoded names in helpers. All of them are `DisplayFor` and `DisplayNameFor`. I'll show you code tomorrow. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Stop using such bad practices! (using `MyDBContext` inside a view model, html tables for layout etc.) Model binding is working but it needs values to bind! Your not rendering controls for any property of `Applicant` except `ApplicantID` so thats all that is bound. Your using `RenderPartial` for the recordings and passing it only a property of the model so the control names do not match your model properties so that will also be null. You haven't shown the partial view so hard to understand what you mean by _I would like to choose and add to Application_

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll change the code. Thanks for your advice on `MyDBContext`. I though I'd need it to populate `SelectItem` objects in ViewModel. Regarding the rendering controls, Can I ask a question to confirm I understood what you meant by _"except `ApplicantID` so thats all that is bound"_. I know it may sound stupid but do I need controls like `Text Box` so that Model Binder can actually bind values to parameter(s) in an Action? Cheers!

Comment: Yes you need controls (input, select, textarea) in order to post back values, although because you not editing them its really not necessary to post back the values except the ID (generally better performance to just call the database and get the `Applicant` again).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. Now, that's clear on Model Binding :) I have edited the question. Hopefully, I explained slightly better what I meant by adding recordings. Basically I want to list all and then have an option to choose which of them will be added to the table `Application`. I am confused about PartialView though. If what I've done causes mismatch of controls with the model, what would you suggest instead? I would like to keep the PartialView because I use it in two different places.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I'd forgot to do it. Thanks for your comments as well :)

Comment: So how do you select the recordings? Can you just use a listbox to display and select them, or do you want to show more details of each recording with a checkbox for selection? (you need to show the partial view so I can better understand)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have just added PartialView. I'd like to use a tabled version with selection boxes to tick and show more details of recordings! Looking at the PartialView I think one of the problems is there are no controls but labels and I guess based what I have learned today :), here, `Model Binder` cannot bind them. The question would be then what can I use to orevent use from editting the fields yet enforce a Model Binder to bind at least `RecordingID`!

Comment: You have a few problems such as using a `foreach` loop which wont name your controls correctly - they all have the same `id` (invalid html) and `name` attribute. Give me an hour and then I'll post an answer that fixes some of the other issues as well.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The `RecordingModelViewApp` has `RecordingID` which I did not happen to include in PartiaView. Perhaps this can hrlp :) BTW you have already helped me a lot for which I am really grateful! I can also add the `RecordingViewModelApp` if that could also have any use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to fix the view model. A view model should only contain simple properties representing what you want to display and/or edit

View model

```
public class ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel
{
  public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
  public Application Application { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RecordingViewModelApp> Recordings { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public SelectList UsageTypeSelectList { get; private set; }
  public SelectList UsageEndAppSelectList { get; private set; }
}
```

Controller (note validation checks omitted)

```
public ActionResult Create(int ApplicantID) // assume you must have a custom route for this?
{
  ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel viewModel = new ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel();
  Applicant applicant = dbContext.Applicants.Find(ApplicantID);
  viewModel.Applicant = applicant;
  viewModel.Title = string.Format("Create a new application for {0} {1} {2}", applicant.title, applicant.firstName, applicant.lastName);
  viewModel.Recordings = getViewModel(dbContext.Recordings.ToList(), dbContext); // not sure what this is?
  viewModel.UsageTypeSelectList = new SelectList(dbContext.UsageTypes.OrderBy(ut => ut.UsageTypeName), "UsageTypeID", "UsageTypeName");
  viewModel.UsageEndAppSelectList = new SelectList(dbContext.UsageEndApps.OrderBy(uea => uea.UsageEndAppName), "UsageEndAppID", "UsageEndAppName");  
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
@model Project.ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.Applicant.ApplicantID) // include for post back but Application.ApplicationID not necessary (its a new application!)
  <h3>Details of the applicant</h3>
  // Add display detail for applicant, but use css for layout (position, floats etc), not tables (which are for tabular data)
  <h3>Details of the application</h3>
  // Add controls for Application but use LabelFor() so the label is associated with the control (otherwise its not a label)
  @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Application.ApplicationNo)
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Application.ApplicationNo) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Application.ApplicationNo)
  ....
  <h3>List of recordings</h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      .... // add table headings
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Recordings) // This uses a custom editor template to display and select recordings
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

EditorTemplate (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RecordingViewModelApp.cshtml`)

Note you must use either a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` to render collections. The `foreach` loop you used just renders duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name` attributes without the correct indexers so will not post back to a collection.

```
@model RecordingViewModelApp
<tr>
  <td class="display-field">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected) // required for postback
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RecordingID) // required for postback
  </td>
  <td class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileLocation)</td>
  .... // other display properties
</tr>
```

POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ApplicantApplicationRecordingsViewModel model)
{
  // model is now bound with the Applicant ID, all the properties of Application
  // and the collection of Recordings with their ID and IsSelected property.
}
```

Comment: Stephen, after adding your `EditorTemplate` it renders the list of recording fine but when I press `Submit`, it throws exception "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value". I tried to fill all fields related to `Application` and it's the same. I put breakpoint at first line in POST Create controller and web application is not even reaching this breakpoint.

Comment: In PartialView, I have changed `forloop` to `for`, added `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).RecordingID)` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).IsSelected)` however The `RecordingVIewModelApp` is null.

Comment: @ZikO, You cant use a PartialView, only the `EditorTemplate` (delete the partial). As for the error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value`, I cant even see where you have a property named `value` so it does not make sense. And if it does not reach the first line of the POST method, how it it throwing an exception?

Comment: I know Stephen. The exception occurs when I add and apply the EditorTemplate you have provided. I don't have anything like this `Parameter: value` in code and I am trying to figure out where it could be. I guess I'd better close this topic. Thanks for your assistance here.

Comment: Are then any `Recordings`? It might be null!

Comment: Yes. I have plenty of them. I am operating on dummy data so I have like 23 of them.

Comment: Another problem I found is that `SelectList`s are empty in the POST `Create` action. Since they are not bound, I guess the Model Binder does not post them back.

Comment: I am afraid my knowledge is not good enough to cope with such complex problems. I need a better understanding of how Model Binder works :/ I am going to look for something in Google. If you know about links that could help me, I will be grateful :)

Comment: If you have `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Application.UsageTypeID, Model.UsageTypeSelectList, "-- Select Usage --")` then they will be bound

Comment: @ZikO. What I suggest you do is to start with a simple model, just a few properties and test, then add more properties, `SelectLists` etc and keep testing, then add collections and `EditorTemplates` and keep testing.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I will build this from simplest form and see how far I can go :)   Thanks

Comment: Hi again. I am happy to say that it's working ... almost. I provide just a fixed hard coded list of recordings for this test. What's left is that tricky freaky list of recordings to choose from :p

Comment: Just make sure you use an `EditorTemplate` and that you name it correctly (to match the class name).

Comment: It's the same error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value.

Comment: I have tried to list recordings manually using simple for loop and data are not bound again. I have noticed that all names for `HiddenFor` and `CheckBoxFor` are named like `Recordings[0].RecordingID`, `Recording[0].IsSelected` etc. Whereas controller name for ApplicantID is just `ApplicantID`.

Comment: Stephen, If you still read this, the error has something to do with `bool IsSelected` property in my ViewModel. I changed it to its Nullable version and it started working. The recordings are bound now. The only issue is that I cannot use `CheckBoxFor` but `EditorFor` which gives me DropDown list with `True`,`False`, and `Not set`.

Comment: You should not need to change that. Clearly there are other problems. And `Recordings[0].RecordingID`, `Recording[0].IsSelected` are correct because `Recordings` is a collection (the `..[#]..` is the indexer) - and the name for `ApplicantID` will actually be `Applicant.ApplicantID`